# Splitting C char array into words

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I am trying to split a given char array into separate strings. I am doing this by putting the address of each word into an array, and then getting the string from the address to print.

So I have updated my code but now the program freezes after printing the numArgs but before "test2." I don't understand why.

```
----------------old code-----------------------   
char* parseArgs(char* comPtr){
    char *args[100] = {0};
    char *token;
    int i = 0;
    token = strtok(comPtr, " ");
    while(token != NULL){
        args[i] = malloc(100);
        args[i] = &token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    return *args;
}

char* args = parseArgs(comPtr);
int i = 0;
while(i < numArgs){
    printf("arg%d: %s\n",i,&args[i]);
    i++;
}
-----------------------end old code--------------------

------------------new code------------------------
int countArgs(char* comPtr){
    char *token;
    int i = 0;
    token = strtok(comPtr, " ");
    while(token != NULL){
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    return i;
}

char** parseArgs(char* comPtr){
    printf("test1");
    char** args = calloc(100, sizeof(char*));
    char* token;
    int i = 0;
    while(token = strtok(comPtr, " ")){
        args[i] = token;
    }
    printf("test2");
    return args;
}

printf("ComPtr: %s\n",comPtr);
char* path = "/bin/";
//int pid = fork(); //pid always 0 so using pid = 1 to test
//printf("PID:%d",pid);
int pid = 1;
printf("PID:%d",pid);
if(pid != 0){
    int numArgs = countArgs(comPtr);
    printf("test1");
    printf("NumArgs: %d\n",numArgs);
    printf("test2");
    char** args = parseArgs(comPtr);
    int i = 0;
    printf("test3");
    while(i < numArgs){
        printf("arg%d: %s\n",i,args[i]);
        printf("test4");
        i++;
    }
}
else{
    //waitpid();
}
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Umm: `args[i] = malloc(100); args[i] = &token;` You just leaked memory it two short lines.

Comment: You should't return local variable `args` from function `parseArgs`

Comment: FYI `strtok` will modify its first argument. The spaces in your string are being replaced in `countArgs` with a `\0` then you are trying to parse the spaces (which are no longer there) in `parseArgs`. Also, `i` is never incremented in `parseArgs`.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. How are we supposed to reproduce the error if we can't compile the code? Please show us a minimal, compilable testcase.

Comment: Adding main brackets around the code should compile fine.

Answer (score 2):

You've lost track of where your memory is, your pointers are pointing etc..  If you want to return the list of pointers to tokens, you need something like this:

```
char** parseArgs(char* comPtr){
    char** p_args = calloc(100, sizeof(char*);
    int i = 0;
    char* token;
    while (token = strtok(comPtr, " "))
        p_args[i] = token;
    return p_args;
}

char** p_args = parseArgs(comPtr);
int i = 0;
while(i < numArgs)
{
    printf("arg%d: %s\n",i,p_args[i]);
    i++;
}
free(p_args);
```

I haven't tested it, but it should point you in the right direction.  Have a careful think about how it differs from your program, and use a debugger and/or `printf()` statements in the code to print out addresses and see how it works (or debug it if necessary).

Comment: To be pedantic, wouldn't it be additionally fail-safe if you set `p_args` to `NULL` after `free`ing it?

Comment: Thanks but now I can't even test this due to the program freezing

Comment: @AnishRam: IMHO, there's no overarching best practice for this... can make sense if you're worried about someone using or freeing it again (e.g. in a long complex function body), but you might know that's impossible (e.g. the next source line closes the scope in which `p_args` was created on the stack).  Personally, I very rarely find it useful to NULL pointers, but then I program C++ these days where freeing is often hidden in destructors and the issue rarely exists....

Comment: @TrentWorkman: if a program freezes, then as per my answer you should use a debugger or add `printf()` statements to identify the line it freezes on. You'll never make a programmer if you give up so easily. I'm happy to point you in the right direction, but no chance I'm holding your hand all the way. If you get stuck, ask a specific problem ala "it gets to the line that says `xyz` and this pointer's this and it does that and I expected it to do something else, I tried this but it did that... what's going on and how do I fix it?".

Comment: Thank you but I did tell which lines it froze on. I totally understand about holding my hand but I just really don't understand why it would freeze where it does. It freezes between two printf () statements and that would seem to me as something wrong with printf

Comment: Thanks guys I got it. Running strtok twice was messing it up. Also strtok had to use NULL as argument not comPtr everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the pointer array 'char *args[100]' as global variable. In your program your are allocating memory to the local pointer and its life is within the function. so at the end of the function your pointer variable scope ends. Here there is memory leak too.

Answer (score 0):

The freeze is due to

```
int i = 0;
while(token = strtok(comPtr, " ")){
    args[i] = token;
}
```

where you repeatedly - in an infinite loop - find the first token in `comPtr`, `token` becomes `&comPtr[0]` in each iteration (unless the string starts with spaces), and that is assigned to `args[i]`.

After the first call, all calls to `strtok` that shall find further tokens in the same string - if any - should have a `NULL` first argument.

Also, you should probably increment `i` in the loop, since presumably you don't want to overwrite `args[0]` with each new token.