# Weird output from strtok

Tags: c, arrays

I was having some issues dealing with char*'s from an array of char*'s and used this for reference: [Splitting C char array into words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287986/splitting-c-char-array-into-words)

So what I'm trying to do is read in char arrays and split them with a space delimiter so I can do stuff with it. For example if the first token in my char* is "Dog" I would send it to a different function that dealt with dogs. My problem is that I'm getting a strange output.

For example:

INPUT: *cmd = "Dog needs a vet appointment."

OUTPUT: (from print statements) "Doneeds a vet appntment."

I've checked for memory leaks using valgrind and I have none of them or other errors.

```
void parseCmd(char* cmd){ //passing in an individual char* from a char**
  char** p_args = calloc(100, sizeof(char*));
  int i = 0;
  char* token;
  token = strtok(cmd, " ");
  while (token != NULL){
    p_args[i++] = token;
    printf("%s",token); //trying to debug
    token = strtok(NULL, cmd);
  }
  free(p_args);
  }
```

Any advice? I am new to C so please bear with me if I did something stupid. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand:  If you are not saving the list of pointers you get, why to `calloc(3)` them and then free... why using `p_args` array, asssign to it, and finally `free(3)` it?

Comment: I pass in p_args into different functions, I just didn't add that code yet and preemptively put in the free. I just wanted to get strtok working properly first.

Comment: Oh.... sorry for the comment then.

Comment: np I should have clarified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case,

```
token = strtok(NULL, cmd);
```

is *not* what you should be doing. You instead need:

```
token = strtok(NULL, " ");
```

As per the ISO standard:

> `char *strtok(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);`
>
> A sequence of calls to the `strtok` function breaks the string pointed to by `s1` into a sequence of tokens, each of which is *delimited by a character from the string pointed to by `s2`.*

The only difference between the first and subsequent calls (assuming, as per this case, you want the same delimiters) should be using `NULL` as the input string rather than the actual string. By using the *input string* as the *delimiter list* in subsequent calls, you change the behaviour.

You can see *exactly* what's happening if you try the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void parseCmd(char* cmd) {
    char* token = strtok(cmd, " ");
    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("[%s] [%s]\n", cmd, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, cmd);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char x[] = "Dog needs a vet appointment.";
    parseCmd(x);
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs (first column will be search string to use next iteration, second is result of this iteration):

```
[Dog] [Dog]
[Dog] [needs a vet app]
[Dog] [intment.]
```

The first step worked fine since you were using <kbd>space</kbd> as the delimiter and it modified the string by placing a `\0` at the end of `Dog`.

That means the *next* attempt (with the wrong spearator) would use one of the letters from `{D,o,g}` to split. The first matching letter for that set is the `o` in `appointment` which is why you see `needs a vet app`. The third attempt finds *none* of the candidate letters so you just get back the rest of the string, `intment.`.

Comment: Awesome, I don't know how I made that mistake :(

Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

`token = strtok(NULL, cmd);` should be `token = strtok(NULL, " ");`.

The second argument is for `delimiter`.

---

1. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html

Comment: Oh wow, that was incredibly stupid of me. I just assumed it was something else since I was getting similar output. Thanks. Any idea why it still shot out something similar?